# How to use an NSArray not key-value pair with Mantle

Tags: objective-c, github-mantle

If I have a JSON array like this,

```
{
  "list": [
    "javascript", 
    "stockFields",
    "stockLists"
  ]
}
```

and two models like:

```
@interface stockList : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property(nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSArray *stockListItems;

@end

@interface stockListItem : MTLModel

@property(nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *javascript;

@property(nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *stockFields;

@property(nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *stockLists;

@end
```

stockList.m

```
+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
             @"stockListItems":@"list",
             };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)stockLstItemsJSONTransformer {



}
```

How to parse JSON list array attribute storage stockListItem's properyty ?thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You just set them by index if you are sure the indexes are:

```
    javascript = stockListItems[0];
    stockFields = stockListItems[1];
    stockLists = stockListItems[2];
```

Otherwise, you could have another `Dictionary` in `list` to get exact data you want, just like:

```
{
  "list": [
    item1: "javascript", 
    item2: "stockFields",
    item3: "stockLists"
  ]
}
```

and now:

```
javascript = [list objectForKey:@"item1"];
stockFields = [list objectForKey:@"item2"];
stockLists = [list objectForKey:@"item3"];
```

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON with [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/)'s class method `JSONObjectWithData`.

It'll return a `NSDictionary` and then you can access the "list" field like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: nil];
stockListObj.stockListItems = parsedJSON[@"list"];
```

Comment: sorry~i want to storage list array with stockListItem's property!!pls tell me again!thanks~
How can use + (NSValueTransformer *)stockLstItemsJSONTransformer?